# Angular 4 remove default value from BehaviorSubject?

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

Is there a way to remove the default value upon invoking *next()* on a *BehaviorSubject*
? This question is case-specific as I have an **array of objects as a BehaviorSubject** to which I append new elements when I call next() on it (**I only want to append the new array onto the existing one, not overwrite it with the new one from response**). Please see the code below for clarification:

```
private posts = new BehaviorSubject<Array<Object>>([{'post_body':'Owls are creepy', 'subject':'BlahBlah'}]);
loadedPosts = this.posts.asObservable();
fetchPagePosts = (number = 1) => this.http.get(`API_URL`).subscribe(
  (res: Response) => {
    this.posts.next(this.posts.getValue().concat(res.json()));
  }
);
```

What happens is that, when newer posts are loaded (I often invoke the *fetchPagePosts* function), the first (default) post remains on top. Is there a prebuilt way to remove it instead of manually checking for its existence?

Comment: You want an push latest one on top? don't quite understand the problem here

Comment: @FanCheung No, I want to remove the default one from the array. It remains as the first element.

Comment: use  this.posts.next(res.json());?

Comment: @FanCheung That will just overwrite the whole array with the new array received from `res.json()` ?

Comment: @FanCheung Although that is a (very) cute workaround, I need the default element.

Comment: You can probably replace behavior subject with something else, like observable.of([...]).scan() to have more fexibility,  i just find the use case a bit strange. need to see more code to judge